# Error while trying to compile in TinyOS

Tags: jvm, tinyos

I was trying to run Blink application in TinyOS installed in Ubuntu16.06.

```
`make telosb reinstallbsl,/dev/ttyUSB0`
```

It is showing that

```
../../support/make/Makerules:56:  Old TinyOS environment variables detected.

This version of the TinyOS make system has deprecated the TOSDIR, TOSROOT,
and MAKERULES environment variables. Generally, you shouldn't need
environment variables with this version of the TinyOS make system, and if
you are not using any older versions of TinyOS on your system you should
delete these environment variables. If you wish to leave these variables
but hide this warning, set the TINYOS_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING environment
variable. If you are looking to compile against a different TinyOS tree,
configure the makefiles used when compiling, or setup an external TinyOS
tree with additional source files, please visit
https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/blob/master/support/make/README.md
for more information about the TinyOS make system.
```

Further down it showed:

```
`<JAVA_HOME> /lib/ext exists, extensions mechanism no longer supported; 
Use -classpath instead.
.Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
../../support/make/Makerules:362: recipe for target 'wiring_check' failed
make: *** [wiring_check] Error 1`
```

when I checked the `java -version`, it showed,

```
<JAVA_HOME>/lib/ext exists, extensions mechanism no longer supported; Use -classpath instead.
.Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Please tell me how to correct this.

Comment: This looks to me like you have JDK 9 installed as that would give the error message about the ext directory no longer being supported.  First thing is to download a fresh copy of JDK 8 from Oracle, set JAVA_HOME and your PATH and see where that takes you.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the tinyOS 3. Different from tinyOS 2-*, It won't use TOSDIR, TOSROOT AND MAKERULES environment variables. You should install the tinyos 2-1-2 and use that environment variables. Or you should follow the installation guide of tinyOS 3-* and delete all that older version environment variables.